# Extending claims identity in MVC5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, claims-based-identity, asp.net-identity, owin

My mvc5 application uses aspnet.identity authentication. Owin middleware is configured to use application cookies.
All i want to achieve is to show user full name instead of the login in the LoginPartial view.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Hello, " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
```

I guess i need to customize my identity during creating it with user manager. Am I right?

```
    private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
    {
        var identity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
    }
```

I know I can store it in the session but what is the right way to store additional information?

Comment: My answer here is a short guide on adding claims to the identity token. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27683169/identity-2-0-creating-custom-claimsidentity-eg-user-identity-getuserbyidint/27694574#27694574

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use claims to store the user's full name. Here is an [article on how to add and retrieve custom claims using ASP.NET Identity](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/12/using-claims-in-aspnet-identity.html).