# Identity 2.0: Creating custom ClaimsIdentity eg: User.Identity.GetUserById<int>(int id) for Per Request Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2, class-extensions, razor-3

See this similar question: [Need access more user properties in User.Identity](http://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/workitem/2263)

I would like to create custom authentication methods to use with my Razor Views that allows easy access `IdentityUser` properties relational to the User.Identity object but I am not sure how to go about it. I want to create several custom extensions similar to `User.Identity.GetUserName()`, `User.Identity.GetUserById()`, etc... instead of using this [ViewContextExtension](http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-accessing-base-controller.html) method. My Authentication type is currently the default type `DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie` from VS2013 MVC5 template. As Shoe stated, I need this claim to be inserted after the user signs in.

My questions is:

**How and where do you create a custom claim that has an out parameter of `this IIdentity` under IPrincipal?**

This would allow me to access User properties via CookieAuthentication in a View for entities in a DDD setting where I have multiple DbContexts in a single app using Identity 2.0. I will eventually use WebAPI, but for now I want to keep it as simple as possible. I have found [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064271/asp-net-mvc-set-custom-iidentity-or-iprincipal) but it is geared towards Web Forms using Tickets. Not sure the difference between tickets and tokens either?

This is the current approach that uses `ViewContext` from a base controller:

**View:**

```
    @using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
    @using Globals.Helpers
    @using Identity //custom Identity for Domain
    @using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin
    
    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
          var url = @ViewContext.BaseController().GetAvatarUrlById(User.Identity.GetUserId<int>());
  
        //...
    }
```

**BaseController.cs**

```
        public string GetAvatarUrlById(int id)
        {

            var user = UserManager.FindById(id);

            return "../../" + user.ImageUrl;
        }
```

**Extensions.cs**

```
    public static class ViewContextExtension
    {
        public static BaseController BaseController(this ViewContext view)
        {
            var baseController = (BaseController)view.Controller;
            return baseController;
        }
    }
```

What I am looking for is but where & how?

**View:**

```
<img src="@User.Identity.GetAvatarUrl()" alt="User.Identity.GetAvatarUrl()" />
```

**SOLUTION**

I simply edited the **Extension.cs** file and used inheritance for the Base controller which is used for the _LoginPartial.cshtml & edited the `ViewContextExtension` class:

```
    #region ViewContextExt
    public static class ViewContextExtension
    {
        public static BaseController BaseController(this ViewContext view)
        {
            var baseController = (BaseController)view.Controller;
            return baseController;
        }

        public static string GetAvatarUrl(this IIdentity identity)
        {
            return ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).Claims.First(c => c.Type == "AvatarUrl").Value;
        }
    }
}
# endregion
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `IIdentity` object in MVC is going to be the issued token that corresponds to the identity of the user. This differs from whatever object or method you use on the back-end that represents the user (say a `User` class). If you want to use the user's identity to get a custom value then you need to put it into their claims object (ie the identity token) when they sign in (or at some other point in time).

You can add a claim at any time by giving the user an identity.

```
AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("PhoneNumber", "123-456-7890"));
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
```

When you have that claim inserted into their token you can retrieve it using an extension method like this...

```
public static string GetPhoneNumber(this IIdentity identity)
{
    return ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirstValue("PhoneNumber");
}
```

Razor

```
@using MyProject.Web.Extensions

<img src="@User.Identity.GetPhoneNumber()" />
```

Comment: Once I get solution complete with example I will mark answer :-)

Comment: Thanks Shoe I was actually reading on PerRequest Validation prior to your answer so I was almost there. SO what you are saying is if I want to redirect anonymous users who are attempting to view pages which its ActionResult returns a model that use parameter == User.Identity.GetUserId a simple if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) will not suffice? I need to validate that the models Id is equal to to the User.Identity.GetUserId? I understand that it would make most sense not to pass any id when it comes to preventing anonymous users but for arguments sake. Thanks again!

Comment: If you want to redirect anonymous users you should do it at the controller level, though a properly placed `Authorize` attribute is generally better unless it's a page that can be viewed by both anonymous and authenticated users. You don't have to check the model's id against the identity because they should be the same. The point I was making was that the Identity of the user (User.Identity) is a different object with different properties than your `User` class, and you can't simply grab the `User` properties without first putting them into the Identity object (via claims).

Comment: Ok so the [Authorize] attribute is in fact validating the claim/token not just the user is in a role (unless specified). Was curious because the default template in VS2013 for MVC 5 doesn't implement much Authentication. Now looking at the ManageController again it does use [Authorize] attribute. It looks like I have a lot of reading to do on Identity 2.0 in order to create the necessary boilerplate code for both Web API and MVC usage. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Yes that's correct. The template gives a small bootstrapped project but isn't really meant as a tutorial.

Comment: To add to your answer Shoe, instead of using claims we can override the HttpContext.User by implementing IPrincipal instead of IIdentity I think? Either way we are creating these objects within the controller which totally makes sense now. Will have to look into the difference between claims and [LukeP's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064271/asp-net-mvc-set-custom-iidentity-or-iprincipal#answer-1524305) approach using IPrincipal.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the solution using the answer to this [SO question by LukeP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064271/asp-net-mvc-set-custom-iidentity-or-iprincipal#answer-1524305) but as Shoe notes, this is pre-MVC5 and we could simply put in a Claim instead.

I made the following alterations:

```
    interface IDomainPrincipal : IPrincipal
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        string UserName { get; set; }
        string AvatarUrl { get; set; }
    }

    public class DomainPrincipal : IDomainPrincipal
    {
        public IIdentity Identity { get; private set; }
        public bool IsInRole(string role) { return false; }

        public DomainPrincipal(string email)
        {
            this.Identity = new GenericIdentity(email);
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string AvatarUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I used `@User.Id, @User.UserName, @User.AvatarUrl` in my @Razor Views respectively

Comment: The answer you link to is pre-MVC5. You're making it harder for yourself. MVC 5 has claims already. Extending IPrincipal to accomplish the same goal isn't necessary.

Comment: Alright thanks Shoe. I get it now. I will offer my solution using your approach. After all, the goal is to use MVC5.