# Where to set DBContext static property for an Entity Framework global filter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2

I'm attempting to build a multi-tenant MVC web application which is so far progressing quite well. In my application I've extended asp.net Identity 2 User properties to include an OrganisationId, where each users created is assigned against to an Organisation. i.e. 1 organisation can have many users associated to it. The database can have many organisations.

Here is a previous post of mine showing how I [extended asp.net identity and retrieve the OrganisationId of the logged in user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335353/how-to-extend-available-properties-of-user-identity/31340030#31340030).

To achieve global filtering with Entity Framework, so that the logged in user can only see their associated organisations data, I'm using the [Entity Framework Dynamic Filter](https://github.com/jcachat/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters) found on github.

I've managed to get the global filter to work based on the example code provided from github, where I create a static property in the DBContext which can be dynamically updated based on the logged in user.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    //  A static/globally scoped value that will be used to restrict queries by their OrganisationId.
    public static long CurrentUserOrganisationID { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        ....

        //Filters
        modelBuilder.Filter("Employees_CurrentOrganisation", (Employee e) => e.OrganizationId, () => CurrentUserOrganisationID);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm faced with is where in my MCV application should I set/refresh the current users OrganisationId static property in the DBContext? I could set it during the login process but if the user quits the application without clicking "logout" the application will remember that their logged in the next time they browse to the application and not execute the login controller method.

The code that needs to execute to set the static OrganisationId property is:

```
ApplicationDbContext.CurrentUserOrganisationID = Convert.ToInt64(HttpContext.User.Identity.GetOrganizationId());
```

My apologies for the title of this post, I'm not sure of the best terminology to pose the question! (newbie alert)

Comment: *'where I create a static property in the DBContext which can be dynamically updated based on the logged in user'* - What will happen if two users are accessing the site at the same time?

Comment: Statics are statics regardless. You'll have one `ApplicationDbContext.CurrentUserOrganisationID` per AppDomain, not per request or user. Why not just use claims?

Comment: Hi both, thanks for your replies. I guess using a static property in my DBContext is not a good idea then. After running a test I can confirm you're correct. How silly of me! I just followed the example as shown in the downloadable github example for Dynamic Filters. Not sure how I should approach setting the filter based on the user when logged in. A claim is created when the user is logged in storing the claim, I just need a way to set the filter for the individual users logged in.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use the static property to define the `OrganisationId` of the user. Static properties have a tendency to be global in the application and if you have an incorrect lifescope for DbContext, you'll get incorrect `OrganisationId` for multiple users.

If you are using DI framework, I would inject `IPrincipal` and get `OrganisationId` from claims and then use it in filtering.

Or if you don't mind coupling of your DB-code with Web-code you can do this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ....

    //Filters
    modelBuilder.Filter("Employees_CurrentOrganisation", (Employee e) => e.OrganizationId, () => Convert.ToInt64(HttpContext.User.Identity.GetOrganizationId()));
}
```

But this approach adds negative effects of adding dependency between Web and DB. I do prefer injecting user object into DBContext through constructor and defining filters on the data from the injected user.

Comment: Thanks @trailmax I will look into injecting user object into DBContext. Can't say I know much about this approach but I will do some googling around it. I currently use a claim for my OrganisationId as shown in one of the posts I linked to above. I used the static property as it was one of the methods detailed in the [github example for the EF Dynamic Filter](https://github.com/jcachat/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters).

Comment: Comment by the creator of the code. **Filter to restrict all queries on BlogEntries to only those for the current user. Global filter is used here with a delegate so that it's evaluated every time it's needed. IMPORTANT: Make sure if a delegate/Func<object> is used for the value that it has GLOBAL scope in your application.  In this example, CurrentAccountID is static.  If it were not static, setting the CurrentAccountID would have no effect since the Func would be using the instance on the DbContext that was used in the call to OnModelCreating - which only happens once per app lifetime**

Comment: Sorry to add another comment, but if I couple my DB-code with Web-code, won't an error be thrown if the user isn't logged in, thus OrganisationId will be null?

Comment: @RobHurd If user is unauthenticated, should they even reach the point where they can read data from your DB? Anyway, you are working with a delegate - check if user is unauthenticated and return null or something appropriate for the filter.

Comment: Regarding the comment from the author - `OnModelCreating` happens every time you create a new instance of `DbContext` and in web-application that should happen on every http request.