# I can't access session inside ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

Just a quick question:

How come i can't access `Session[key]` on my ActionFilterAttribute class?

(VS always change it to sessionChecker if i press [ )

How am i supposed to get and check the session value? I need to retrieve the `ID` that is stored in the session and use it to compare for something.

Here is my code:

**Login(post):**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("login")]
    public ActionResult login_post(string uname, string pword)
    {

        using (EmployeeContext emp = new EmployeeContext())
        {
            //h student log = new student();
            int success = emp.login.Where(x => x.username == uname && x.password == pword).Count();
            if (success == 1)
            {
                int id = (from logs in emp.login
                          join rol in emp.roles on logs.role equals rol.id
                          where logs.username == uname
                          select logs.id).First();

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(uname, false);

               Session["Login"] = id;

                return RedirectToAction("Details", "Enrollment", new { id = id });
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**ActionFilterAttribute class**

```
    public class CustomChecker: ActionFilterAttribute
    {
    public string test { get; set; }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        int t_id;

        t_id = //sessionChecker keeps on appearing whenever i try typing "Session". I get red line from it. How do i access the session?
```

Comment: Show your code. How are you trying to access `Session`?

Comment: Hello, from my login, i store them first like this `Session["Login"] = id;` then i try to access them from my `ActionFilterAttribute` class like the same as well but i get red line.

Comment: Show your code - we cant guess what your doing wrong!

Comment: Alright i put my code. please check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to access it from the `filterContext` (`Session` is not a property of `ActionFilterAttribute`)

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
  int id = (int)filterContext.HttpContext.Session["Login"];
}
```

Comment: my i know why? isn't `Session` supposed to be at the top most and should be accessible anywhere from the application?

Comment: Because you attribute inherits from class `ActionFilterAttribute` which does not have a property named `Session`. Note also you will want to check for `null` before you assign the value (because it may be `null` the first time you access this method)

Comment: Alright, one last question. If a session timed out, what's its value going to be? back to null?

Comment: It will be `null` so you will need to check for that and call the database again to get the value, But you would be far better of storing the value in the cookie (e.g. if your using `Identity`, then use `Claims`)

Comment: thank you so much for the answers. can you link me a good material wherein i can read something regarding `Claims` ?

Comment: Lots of articles on the web and question/answers on SO, but you could look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335353/how-to-extend-available-properties-of-user-identity) and [this](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-2) to get you started. And if you want your own `MembershipProvider`, then [this article](http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article147)