# Implement single sign on ASP .Net Web Application current using forms based authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-sign-on, adfs

We currently have an  Asp .Net web application  (Framework  4.5) using  Forms based  authentication. A few of our clients  are asking for integration with their  applications and does not want to  have separate  login accounts.

What would be the  best way to implement this? The solution should be able to validate against different identity providers.

A consultant has suggested to  convert the current web app to be claims-aware but not sure how to  proceed with it or where to start .

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Read the doc yet? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims (may only be suitible for .NET core applications)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Our app still use web forms though so it may not be applicable.

Comment: Are all other apps web apps or some are desktop/winforms/wpf apps?

Comment: Mix of web and desktop apps. Ideally the solution  should be able to support both.

Comment: This might be meet your requirment http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/

Comment: The consultant is right though it's not very useful info. The new security model is called 'claims'. Somehow I don't think this is going to be a simple rewrite. I'm guessing you're going to have to rewrite using the new claims security, and make your 'forms authorisation feed into it. In other word you won't use forms authentication anymore, you'll use claims. And a login screen that looks like forms authentication will just happen to feed into it... thats my theory

Comment: Here's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36078322/how-to-migrate-from-forms-authentication-to-asp-net-identity which says much the same thing: migrate to claims (somehow) and add you custom (user/pass in a database) authentication to that

Comment: This might be what you're after: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/security/claims-aware-aspnet-app-forms-authentication

Answer (score 0):

Making an application claims-aware implies adding support for one of:

- WS-Federation
- SAML 2.0
- OpenID Connect / OAuth

This then enables the application to talk to an IDP for SSO e.g. ADFS, Azure AD, identityserver, Auth0.

In the Microsoft world, web apps use the OWIN NuGet packages for WS-Fed (WIF) or OIDC. For SAML, look [here](https://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html).

Desktop apps use ADAL or the later version MSAL.

ADFS e.g. only authenticates against AD. If you want to authenticate against a DB as well, you federate ADFS with e.g. identityserver or Auth0 both of which have that ability.

Comment: Thank you  @nzpcmad. What would be advantage of  using ADFS as  IDP?   Why not use IdentityServer/Auth0 directly.  I'm  trying to figure out  what would be the best solution architecture moving forward.   We currently do not have Active directory and would only require the claims based   for certain users.

Comment: It depends on your use case. Does the IDP have to be on-premises? Are you a Microsoft shop with Sharepoint, O365, Azure, CRM Dynamics? Do you want support? Do you have ADFS already? They all do the same thing. ADFS integrates with all Microsoft products. identityserver is free. Auth0 is SaaS.