# ASP.NET MVC 5 create global variable from current user email

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My current site uses two databases, one that stores the users directly and another one that stores additional data using the user email. I need to extract data (an identification number) from this other table, so I have created a model that operates like this:

**ZivoyAccount.cs**

```
namespace ZivoyPublicaciones.Models
{
    public class ZivoyAccount
    {
        //Database for additional data
        private PPublicEntities db = new PPublicEntities();
        //Database with user roles
        private zivoypostEntities userdb = new zivoypostEntities();
        public Int64 UserIdentification { 
            get {
                //Get the User Identity
                String UserIdentity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
                var UserData = userdb.AspNetUsers.Find(UserIdentity);
                //Get the User Email
                var UserEmail = UserData.Email;
                //Get the Data from Other Database
                var ZivoyUserData = db.Users.Find(UserEmail);
                return ZivoyUserData.user_gkey;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

But I have been reading that this isn't the right behaviour since this variables get set for all users, and I need them to be set for each user. How could I accomplish this?

I'm calling my model on a father controller so that I can use this variable on all my child controller

**AuthorizationController.cs**

```
namespace ZivoyPublicaciones.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class AuthorizationController : Controller
    {
        protected ZivoyAccount UserProfiler = new ZivoyAccount();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can extend userdb and store user_gkay right inside it.  You can find example on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335353/how-to-extend-available-properties-of-user-identity