# Adding properties to users

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I would like to know how I can add more properties to users in my website.
I am using the default user template that is made with a MVC project.
I tried using the answer to
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335353/how-to-extend-available-properties-of-user-identity) post, but I keep getting:

> The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created

I believe I am missing something that isn't written in that post, can anyone point me to what I need to do?
Thanks.

Comment: Your ApplicationDbContext inherits from IdentityContext? You have the correct project selected in console window?

Comment: Yes, ApplicationDbContext inherits from IdentityContext. I did not modify the default template that comes with the project on creation. I only added a property to the ApplicationUser class as instructed in the post I linked.

Comment: @master2080 Try deleting the record created in your _MigrationHistory table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the answer.
The default user identity model comes with it's own context.
Everywhere I looked, people were always creating an additional context and I thought they both worked together just fine.
Apparently You need to work with each one separately(add migrations to each, and update database with each).

Answer (score 1):

You have to migrate and update your DB after changing default User model in Identity. Try with that.

Comment: I did, but there were no changes. Just adding a property to the ApplicationUser doesn't seem to do anything to a migration.

Comment: After changing User properties, you should migrate that user to update db with that properties. Did you enabled migrations? Something like this:
1. Enable-Migrations
2. Add property
3. Add-Migration “YouMigrationName”
4. Update-Database

Comment: Yes, I did enable migrations and know how to use them(on some level), but adding the property doesn't make a new migration have any changes.(I did try to update regardless, but the property is not added to the table).