# How to extend User Identity with an IEnumerable/Collection property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

Similar to this question: [How to extend available properties of User.Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335353/how-to-extend-available-properties-of-user-identity)

When a user logs in I'd like to load the departments my user has an association with.  I'm guessing that I'd add a property to the `ApplicationUser` class like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid, GuidUserLogin, GuidUserRole, GuidUserClaim>
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            return userIdentity;
        }


        public IEnumerable<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    }
```

My question is how/where would I populate the collection, and then how would I access the property later in my controllers.  From what I understand, claims would be OK for simple types - an Id for example - but can they be used with collections?

I'm assuming once I have this property loaded, I'd be able to query the collection without hitting the database each time I need this information about the user - which will be often.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps have a domain entity for storing the collection and reference the Id of the ApplicationUser to set up a relationship?

Comment: In the constructor of ApplicationUser class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, create the collection entity, i.e. Department. Then reference the Id of the ApplicationUser entity within that.

Assuming you use entity framework code-first, here is an example:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid, GuidUserLogin, GuidUserRole, GuidUserClaim>
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            return userIdentity;
        }

        public ApplicationUser()
        {
           Departments = new Collection<Department>();
        }

        public ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    }



public class Department
{

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    protected Department()
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response Umut.  I don't get where you would hit the DB to populate the Departments collection.

Comment: As I pointed out, if you are using code-first migrations, you would first add your Department entity into the DbContext class as a property of type DbSet. Then create & run a migration. Whenever you get an instance of a user from the db with entity framework, the departments will be populated for your. for more information on setting up relationships please take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx)