# Outputting user data into view MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm still learning MVC5 and I'm having issues figuring out how to output data from a user's table. I added fields to the register form that takes a phone number and driver license number and I can successfully send the data to the database, but I'm having issues retrieving it and displaying it in the view for logged in user. I've looked at examples, but I must be missing something because I can output some of the data, but not the fields I want specifically. (Phone number and driver license number)
[image]

Here's my code

Index.cshtml

```
 User Data: 



  @{

       System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = Context.User 
     as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal;
       System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity id = claimsPrincipal.Identity 
       as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;
       foreach (var claim in id.Claims)
       {
           <p>Claim: @claim.ToString()</p>
           <p>Claim More: @claim.p</p>
       }
}
```

HomeController

```
 [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationUser.MyDbContext()));

        // Get the current logged in User and look up the user in ASP.NET Identity
        var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        // Recover the profile information about the logged in user
        ViewBag.DriverLicense= currentUser.DrivingLicense;
        ViewBag.PhoneNumbers= currentUser.PhoneNumbers;

        return View();


    }
```

ApplicationUser.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace Vidly2.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string DrivingLicense { get; set; }

        [Required]

        public int PhoneNumbers { get; set; }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }

        public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
        {
            public MyDbContext()
                : base("DefaultConnection")
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need any additional info

Comment: On which entity class did you store the additional info?

Comment: I think I provided all the relevant controllers/classes. What do you mean?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335353/how-to-extend-available-properties-of-user-identity

Comment: That was useful. I got it working. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extend available properties of User.Identity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335353/how-to-extend-available-properties-of-user-identity)