# Extending User information inside asp.net mvc 5 project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have created a new asp.net MVC-5 web application , and I define individual user accounts as the authentication type.

Now when users register a new account they can enter email and password. Now I want to extend the users information when registering their account as follow:-

- First name
- Last name
- Data of birth
- Country
- City
- Address
- Etc…

Now I am not sure what is the recommended way to extend the user info. Now I am trying to do the following 2 steps, as when the project was created a new database has been created automatically and it has a table named “ASPNETUSers”, which store the users info.

1. So I am thinking of adding the additional fields inside this table.
2. Then to modiy the “Account >> Register” view to render the additional fields.

So can anyone advice if my above 2 steps to store additional info about the users upon registration is valid ?or I should not modify the built-in database tables which include the ASPNETUSers ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extend available properties of User.Identity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335353/how-to-extend-available-properties-of-user-identity)