# Editing AspNet.Identity after add

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-identity, identity

I start a project without use security. Then now I add by nugtpackeged AspNet.Identity and need to customize it. In internet I found a lot of tutorials about it.

But I don't find the IdentityUser.cs in Models folder and if I press F12 to go to definition I see a metadata only-read version of IdentityUser.cs.

How can I edit this to add some custom properties?

I see the other Answers here like this:
[How to extend available properties of User.Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335353/how-to-extend-available-properties-of-user-identity)

But where I find the `public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser`?
I need create this?

Another question: I can't edit the class IdentityUser??? because for me it only appears as read only (see the image).

[Image from my screen show only read class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfFWl.png)

[My solution explore. See the model folder is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83N2S.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extend available properties of User.Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335353/how-to-extend-available-properties-of-user-identity)

Comment: @AshiqEmran  I edit my question... I see the other Answers But Where I find the public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser ??? I nedd create this? Another qustion: I can't edit the class IdentityUser??? because for me it appears as read-only.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can not edit that class, only you can **inherit** that class and add your extra properties then use that inherited class then you can easily add value in your extra properties.

Comment: Thanks Ashiq! I'm starting with Identity. It's a first time I try to deploy it in a solution. So I know this question should sound silly, but any hint I already help.