# 'IIdentity' does not contain a definition for 'Score'

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am building a prediction website on ASP.NET core in Visual Studio and of course I need a "score" variable for each user. That's why I added a "score" column to the built-in IdentityUser table by creating a new class with IdentityUser as base class. The only thing I added there is a property called Score.

```
 public class UserIdentity : IdentityUser<Guid>
    {
        public int Score { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I want to display the score in the navbar along with the username of the current user, but I get the error that Score does not exist in the same namespace as the username.

HTML code from my _Layout file (for the navigation bar):

```
@if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
                        {
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <form method="post" asp-action="logout" asp-controller="account">
                                    <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link py-0" style="width:auto">Uitloggen @User.Identity.Name <br /> @Convert.ToString(User.Identity.Score)  punten</button>
                                </form>
                            </li>
                        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way you could do this by using `UserManager`, your login partial should look like this

```
@inject UserManager<UserIdentity> UserManager


@if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
                    {
                       var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <form method="post" asp-action="logout" asp-controller="account">
                                <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link py-0" style="width:auto">Uitloggen @User.Identity.Name <br /> @user.Score  punten</button>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    }
```

**For your _Layout file you could implement this by following way**

```
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>@ViewData["Title"] - WebApplication5</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>

                  @if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
                    {
                       var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <form method="post" asp-action="logout" asp-controller="account">
                                <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link py-0" style="width:auto">Uitloggen @User.Identity.Name <br /> @user.Score  punten</button>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    }
```

Another way you could extend you User Identity based on claim principle. For More Please follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50119780/problems-extending-properties-from-identity-asp-net-core)

Comment: Perhaps I should have mentioned what file the code is from. It is not the login partial, it is the _Layout file.

Comment: There are not much differences between Login partial and _Layout file, Just Inject this two before your Doctype of that _Layout Page!