# How to return user information to View ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory

My view's code[_LoginPartial.cshtml] is like below. I want to show more details like department. How to do it? I succeed in getting departments in IdentityModels.cs. But I don't know how to use it in view.

IdentityModels.cs

```
   var directoryEntry = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry();
    var directorySearcher = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry); 

    directorySearcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(SamAccountName={0}))", mADUser.SamAccountName);

    var result = directorySearcher.FindOne();


    var entry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

var (string)mADUserDirectoryEntry.Properties["department"].Value;
```

_LoginPartial.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Login", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink("Hi" + User.Identity.GetUserName(), "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage", @style = "color: white" })
                <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">ログオフ</a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>

    }
}
```

Comment: The link below solved my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335353/how-to-extend-available-properties-of-user-identity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your View Model is of type `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` you only have properties available that comes out of the box. Unless you extend the class.

Here is how you can do that: [How to extend available properties of User.Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28335353/218408)
Then you will be able to use the department data as `User.Identity.Department` or `User.Identity.GetDepartment()`.