# how to create custom column in aspnetusers table using asp.net core 3.1 mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-3

I have created project using asp.net mvc 3.1 . I have used identity in my  existing project. I want to add columns in aspnetusers  table and used that table in code. How can i do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extend available properties of User.Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335353/how-to-extend-available-properties-of-user-identity)

Comment: Please tell me step by step how to add custom column